Please delay your close vote on salvagable new questions
We, moderators of Arduino SE, noted that recently not suitable questions are closed really fast. While for many questions this is rightful, for some salvageable questions this happens before OP can react to first comments.
We would like to ask you to delay your close vote on new questions which lack some details or clarity but are likely to be edited by OP with the requested details.
While it is true that OP can ask to reopen after they added the requested information to the question, it can take time until the question is reopened and somebody can write an answer.
If is not a problem if at the end OP doesn't add the requested details. After some time the clean-up process will remove the question if it stays without answer. Additionally to the automatic cleanup process I return to questions with zero score after 10/30 days and I handle them.
